# UIwebview in UItableview scrolling issue in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am applying pull to refresh code in tableview. 
I have custom cell with UIwebview in it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil){
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.subviews);
}
// Configure the cell...

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com.au"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[cell.webView loadRequest:request];
return cell;
```

}

in view didLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

}

```
- (void)refresh:(id)sender
{
// do somthing
NSLog (@"Refresh");
[self performSelector:@selector(stopRefresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];


}

- (void)stopRefresh {
    NSLog (@"Stop Refresh");

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

It is behaving properly in iOS 6 and I am able to pull to refresh, but in iOS 7, only web view is scrolling not tableview.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   - (void)refresh:(id)sender
    {
    NSLog (@"Refresh");
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(stopRefresh) withObject:Nil];

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it is not responding to touch… only web view scrolls… :(   …. Event is not passing to tableview...

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 and above, The event is not getting passed from UIWebView scroll end to UITableView bounce due to the hierarchy changes and the framework changes.

Programatically detecting if the scrollview is from UITableView or UIWebView 
if the scrollview is appWebView

```
if([[scrollView superview] isEqual:appWebView]){
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<0) {
        CGPoint currentContentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
        [appTableView setContentOffset:currentContentOffset animated:NO];
    }

}
```

try playing with this part according to your requirement in scrollView delegates.